# Long AMPL model preparation time

Tags: cplex, gurobi, pyomo, ampl

We deal with a large-scale linear optimization problem (~50000 variables and ~4000000 constraints). 
We use **AMPL Studio** modeling environment for problem modeling and then calling linear solver (**CPLEX**, **Gurobi**, etc.).
However, before calling a solver, the preparation process (generation of `LP` or `MPS` file I guess?) of such model takes ~950 seconds.

Profiling shows that most of the time is consumed by **AMPL**'s `genmod` function. Is it normal that preparation of such model (for the solver) takes so long?

If so, could you suggest an alternative way to generate model faster? As far as I am aware, **AMPL** is among the leader's for such job compared to other **AML**s.

Thank You in advance for your response!

Comment: While you haven't provided any code, the most likely root cause is that there are nested forall / sum clauses in the code with a test for membership embedded inside.  Try selectively removing some constraints to identify the one that is causing the slow down.

Comment: The time AMPL needs is more related to the number of nonzero elements than to the number of variables and constraints. Also use `gentimes` to find out where the performance problem lies. I have done some conversions from AMPL to GAMS leading to 10:1 performance improvements, but I think this was partial due to streamlining things and improved formulations. Sometimes GAMS is faster when dealing with sparse data operations.

Comment: Thank You for the response! The problem was in many nested forall / sum loops.